# Chart.js - Tipo Line - JSON - SQL Server

Tags: json, chartjs

Estou montando minha primeira Chart. Quando uso constantes no data o chart renderiza normalmente, mas quando carrego informações do banco sql não tenho o mesmo sucesso. Segue código ...

```
<div id="canvas-holder1" style="width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="chart1" />
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Entrada.aspx/getChartData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var lstReceita = eval(response.d[0]);
            var lstDespesa = eval(response.d[1]);

            var lineChartData = {
                labels: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Receitas",
                    data: lstReceita
                }, {
                    label: "Despesas",
                    data: lstDespesa
                }]
            };

            window.onload = function() {
                var chartEl = document.getElementById("chart1");
                window.myLine = new Chart(chartEl, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: lineChartData,
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Comparativo Gráfico de Performance Financeira'
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        };

        function OnErrorCall(response) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Retira esse `window.onload`, só está a atrapalhar. Depois disso funciona? se não tens algum erro na consola?

Comment: Perfeito Sérgio. Era exatamente este o problema.

Comment: Na máquina de testes funcionou perfeitamente, mas no provedor de hospedagem não renderizou. O que poderia ser isso?

Comment: Tens algum erro na consola? o url `"Entrada.aspx/getChartData"` existe e dá algum resultado?

Comment: A tabela existe, possui dados, a query retorna os dados, mas o json não complementa o trabalho.

Comment: O que dá `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Não trouxe nada. É uma WebMethod. Talvez precise ser configurado no provedor.

Comment: Ok, então é um problema separado desta pergunta e tens de configurar no servidor...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48104/discussion-between-winston-and-sergio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linha `$(function() {` é a maneira jQuery de chamar `window.load`. O código que está dentro de `$(function() {...});` só será corrido quando o DOM estiver carregado. Assim teres a linha `window.onload = function() {...};` é uma redundância e nalguns casos (p.ex. quando houver outros `window.load`) isso vai impedir o código de correr.

Remove `window.onload = function() {...};` e deixa só o que está dentro, isso deve resolver o teu problema.